# JOLT spec array of objects remove key

Tags: json, jolt

I'm trying to understand how to remove the key and object layers for the below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Trying to use a JOLT processor in NIFI to address this data change.

INPUT:

```
 [ {
  "rbr" : {
    "fetchTime" : "2020-07-06T23:46:23.677Z",
    "customMetadata" : {
      "x" : "1",
      "o2" : {
        "x2" : "y"
      }
    }
  },
  "xyz": {
    "fetchTime" : "2020-07-06T23:46:23.677Z",
    "customMetadata" : {
      "x" : "1",
      "o2" : {
        "x2" : "y"
      }
    }
  }
}
]
```

desired output:

```
 [
  {
    "fetchTime" : "2020-07-06T23:46:23.677Z",
    "customMetadata" : {
      "x" : "1",
      "o2" : {
        "x2" : "y"
      }
    },
    "type": "rbr"
  },
  {
    "fetchTime" : "2020-07-06T23:46:23.677Z",
    "customMetadata" : {
      "x" : "1",
      "o2" : {
        "x2" : "y"
      }
    },
    "type": "xyz"

  }
]
```

Comment: Hey and welcome, please attach your tries so we can help, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with simple shift operation

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "fetchTime": "[#2].fetchTime",
          "customMetadata": "[#2].customMetadata",
          "$": "[#2].type"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit 1**

Can shift all the values from current level using `"@": "[#3].&",`

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[#3].&",
            "$1": "[#3].type"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "type": "=firstElement(@(1,type))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: is there a way for me to snag everything here without having to do specific references?  There can be dynaimcally appearing elements inside of the object that I'd like not to have to code for all of the possiiblities?

Comment: For some reason both of those stuff all of the common items across the objects into an array in a single object.

Answer (score -2):

Iterate over the array, and for each `obj` create `newObj` like so:

```
objKey=Object.keys(obj)[0];
newObj=obj[objKey];
newObj.type=objKey;
```

and push into new array.

Comment: Ask is about transforming JSON with Jolt. Your answer seems to be irrelevant.